# javascript function for getting friends, facebook api?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just wrote a test function, been learning to use the facebook api today and here is what I came up with. I have a few questions, first let me show you the code.

```
function getFriends() {
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      FB.api(response.id+'/friends', function(response) {
          $(document.body).prepend('<div class="test-list" style="position: fixed; z-index: 99999999; left: 50%; overflow: scroll; height: 500px; top: 25%;"></div>')
          for (var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
            FB.api('/'+response.data[i].id, function(response) {
              if(response.gender === 'male') {
                  $('.test-list').prepend('<li>'+response.name+'</li>');
              }
            });
          }         
      });
  });
}
```

Am I misusing the api by wrapping it like that? This is the only way I could figure out how to access the users id then use that to get that users friends, after that I loop all the friends and filter only the males.

Now I can use this inside my backbone.js app and create or update a collection with this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Friends with one api call like this:

```
function getFriends(){

    FB.api('/me?fields=friends.fields(gender,id,name)', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all friends by using "taggable_friends" keyword in API call, as follows. The response gives you by default 25 friends/page.

```
FB.api("/me/taggable_friends",
  function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
      /* handle the result */
    }
  }
);
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/taggable_friends